# Trigger scrapy shell using web page

Tags: flask, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and python. I have written a spider which takes start_urls from command line and start scraping. Upto this, everything is fine.

Now, i want to submit start_urls from a web page (Designed using Flask).After clicking on a button, it should trigger the scrapy shell and start scraping websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`scrapyd`](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) project can help with. There is a JSON API which you would use to deploy and run your spiders. This way your Web app part would not be blocked by the active web-scraping process:

> Scrapyd is an application for deploying and running Scrapy spiders. It
>   enables you to deploy (upload) your projects and control their spiders
>   using a JSON API.